# Can you suggest an easy way to draw atoms?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you suggest an easy way to draw these atoms?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\proton(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=myyellow] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
    \node at (#1,#2) {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=myorange] (#1,#2) circle (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
    \fill[shade=ball,ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\sorbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (1.5 and 3.5);
}
\def\porbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (4 and 6);
}
%%Nucleons
\neutron(0.8,0.2)
\proton(0.5,-0.5)
\neutron(-0.25,-0.5)
\neutron(0.55,0.8)
\proton(-0.5,0.2)
\proton(-0.1,0.8)
\proton(0.5,0)
\proton(0.12,0.6)
\proton(0.12,-0.6)
\neutron(-0.25,0)
\neutron(-0.5,0.6)
\neutron(0.5,-0.3)
%%orbits
\porbit(-20,.15)
\porbit(15,.45)
\sorbit(40,.9)
\porbit(65,.6)
\sorbit(100,.3)
\porbit(125,.75)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: If someone has drown a similar athom I can try to change the code.

Comment: take a look at this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281814/23166 for drawing atoms and lines ;)

Comment: yes. But when I compile there is an error :(

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of the question linked to in Chris's answer. If your question is about a particular problem you have with the code there, then rework your question to be much more focused on the code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers to [Draw Bohr atomic model with electron shells in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73410/draw-bohr-atomic-model-with-electron-shells-in-tex) have some examples that could serve as a starting point. The code of some examples there will not compile out of the box on recent TeX distributions. You have to replace `shade=ball` with `shading=ball` on several lines. I guess this is because the TikZ syntax changed over time.

Comment: there is this error

! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'ball' unknown in choice key '/tikz/shade'. I a
m going to ignore this key.
See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.

I have updated the packages with ubuntu

Comment: Try adding `\usetikzlibrary{shadings}` after the first `\usetikzlibrary`.

Comment: there is an error :( i post the code.

Comment: Replace `shade=ball` with `shading=ball` in the orginal code. `\usetikzlibrary{shadings}` should not be needed.