# Drawing Bohr style elements

Tags: chemistry, bohr

I am trying to produce Bohr style diagrams of the elements. I have tried to use the Bohr package but although this produces something almost what I want, but does not show the orbit shapes or the makeup of the nucleus.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{254,241,24}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{234,125,1}

\def\proton(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shading=ball,ball color=myyellow, opacity=0.75] (#1,#2) circle  (10pt);
    \node at (#1,#2) {\texttt{+}};
}
\def\neutron(#1,#2){%
    \fill[shading=ball,ball color=myorange, opacity=0.75] (#1,#2) circle    (10pt);
}
\def\electron{%
    \fill[shading=ball,ball color=gray!30] (0,0) circle (5pt);
    \node at (0,0) {\texttt{-}};
}
\def\sorbit(#1,#2){%
 \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (1.5 and 3.5);
}
\def\porbit(#1,#2){%
  \draw[
  color=violet,
  rotate=#1,
  postaction=decorate,
  decoration={markings,
  mark=at position #2 with {\electron},
}]
  (0,0) ellipse (4 and 6);
}

\begin{document}

Hydrogen
\begin{tikzpicture}
%H Nucleons
\proton(0.2,-0.2)

%H orbits
\sorbit(40,.9)
\end{tikzpicture}

Helium
\begin{tikzpicture}
%He Nuclius
\neutron(-0.1,0.1)
\proton(0.2,-0.2)
\neutron(-0.25,-0.5)
\proton(-0.3,0.1)
%He Orbit
\sorbit(100,.3)
\sorbit(50,0.8)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anybody know of a package which produces this so Ideally I could just type something like \H inside my tikz picture.

Also if any help on automating the location of the protons and neutrons so I don't have to do each one, one by one.

Have tried to use something like [How to create nice-looking nuclei in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448733/how-to-create-nice-looking-nuclei-in-tikz) to produce the nucleus but just don't seem to make it work.

Comment: Your example does not compile for me. Is it possible you want the key `shading=ball` rather than `shade=ball`?

Comment: Thanks @mbert I not sure why it did not compile for you but I have changed it anyway and it still renders for me, hope this was the mismate, so again thank you.

Comment: If you need simpler element diagrams, you can use the [bohr package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bohr)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's not a package, but maybe this does what you want.

We define a command

```
\Bohr[<tikz options>]{<protons>}{<neutrons>}{<electron sequence>}
```

TikZ options include `scale`, `rotate`, etc. Optional.

Examples:

`\Bohr{1}{0}{1} % Hydrogen`

[image]

`\Bohr{3}{4}{2,1} % Lithium`

[image]

`\Bohr{13}{14}{2,8,3} % Aluminum`

[image]

As you can see, the macro adjusts the scale, angle and eccentricity of the electron orbits.

Here is the code. You can easily adjust colors and sizes. There are many more adjustments possible, but I thought I'd see if this was the right idea before I worked any more on it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, ifthen}

\tikzset{proton/.pic={\shade[shading=ball, ball color=protoncolor](0,0) circle[radius=\protonradius];\node[black]{\tiny+};},
    neutron/.pic={\shade[shading=ball, ball color=neutroncolor](0,0) circle[radius=\neutronradius];},
    electron/.pic={\shade[shading=ball, ball color=electroncolor](0,0) circle[radius=\electronradius];\node[black]{\tiny-};}}

\colorlet{protoncolor}{yellow!90!black}
\colorlet{neutroncolor}{orange!90!black}
\colorlet{electroncolor}{gray!30}
\colorlet{orbitcolor}{violet}

\newcommand{\protonradius}{2.5mm}
\newcommand{\neutronradius}{2.5mm}
\newcommand{\electronradius}{1mm}

\newcommand{\Bohr}[4][]{\tikz[#1]{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tot}{#2 + #3}
  \foreach \e[count=\j] in {#4}{\xdef\nume{\j}}
  \foreach \e[count=\j, evaluate=\e as \R using 3*sqrt(#2+#3)/2] in {#4}{
    \draw[orbitcolor, rotate=180/\nume*\j+90/\nume] (0:\R) arc (0:360:{\R} and {\R/(\nume)})
      foreach \s in {1,...,\e} {pic[pos=\s*1/\e+.1]{electron}};
  }
  \foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \r using sqrt((\n-1))/6,
    evaluate=\n as \t using 222.492236*\n,
    ] in {\tot,...,1}{\pic at (\t:\r){neutron};
    \foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using int(\tot/#2*\x)] in {1,...,#2}
        {\ifthenelse{\equal{\n}{\y}}{\pic at (\t:\r){proton};}{}
    }
  }
}}

\begin{document}

\Bohr{1}{0}{1} % Hydrogen

\Bohr{3}{4}{2,1} % Lithium

\Bohr{13}{14}{2,8,3} % Aluminum?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful answer! I think the nucleus in the first image is not concentric witht the orbit.

Comment: @Diaa: Fixed. Thanks!