# Need to horizontally center & align three \Bohr atoms

Tags: multicol, includegraphics, bohr

I'd like to display three atomic structures (C, H, O), centered across a single row on the printed page using the \Bohr package.

I've naively attempted to use the multicol package with \includegraphics, but \includegraphics is looking for a file, not a function.

A plus would be to align the center of the three atoms vertically as well as horizontally.

The \Bohr package is quite useful. Once I can align the three atoms (C, H, O) I'm hoping to apply the same code to the atomic displays presented in the SE article [Draw Bohr atomic model with electron shells in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73410/draw-bohr-atomic-model-with-electron-shells-in-tex#) to better visualize the atomic structures.

Any and all thoughts/ideas appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bohr}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\bohr{}{C}}
\caption{Carbon}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\bohr{}{H}}
\caption{Hydrogen}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\bohr{}{O}}
\caption{Oxygen}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: A variation of Gonzalo's code ...]

Comment: @Simon Dispa-Thank you for responding so quickly. Zarko-Your solution is closer to what I was looking for. In my OP I mentioned how I'd like to adopt a solution to the Bohr atomic model in the link to "Draw Bohr atomic model with electron shells in TeX?" (see post by user11232). This will require me to scale the images, which is why I was attempting to use \includegraphics such as when using: \includegraphics[scale=0.6]. So my question for both your answers: How do I code to scale the Bohr atomic model images, that will likely be too large to fit full size three across, in your answers ? Thks!

Comment: @Simon Dispa-Thank you for the added code to create the added Bohr elements! I should have been more specific in my original posting regarding the elemental LaTeX diagrams posted by user11232, a copy of which I have added herein. I was hoping to implement the code by user11232 for the primary life elements, carbon, hydrogen and oxygen. (Yes, I know there are MANY more living elements, but these three are key to so many aspects of our living environment, without which our world would be very different.) When I have the time, I'm hoping to post a separate, more specific question to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simple tabular will do.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bohr}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{ccc}    
    \bohr{18}{Ar}   &\bohr{6}{C}    &\bohr{11}{Na}\\
    Argon           &Carbon         &Sodium
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question

Bohr diagrams are `tikzpictures`. For either approach, the best way to scale them is to use the parameters provided by the class: nucleus radius, electron radii, and  shell distance (with defaults of 1em, 1.5pt, and 1em). Plus the font size used in the table.

It appears that seven to five elements can be arranged in a single row of a tabular layout, with precise control of element alignments and spacing. (the red lines mark the margins of the text area)

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bohr}
\setbohr{
    shell-dist = 0.45em,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    nucleus-radius= 0.4em,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    electron-radius=1pt,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    insert-missing
}
\usepackage{array}% for newcolumntype
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\footnotesize\arraybackslash}c}%smaller font,

\usepackage{showframe}% ONLY to show the margins
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.1pt}

\begin{document}
    
\parindent0pt  %no indent   
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{7}C@{}}    % seven element in a row    
    \bohr{}{He} &\bohr{}{Ne}    &\bohr{}{Ar}&\bohr{}{Kr}    &\bohr{}{Xe}&\bohr{}{Rn}&\bohr{}{Og}\\
    Helium      &Neon           &Argon      &Krypton        &Xenon      &Radon      &Oganesson
\end{tabular}


\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{5}C@{}}    % five element in a row
    \bohr{}{Ac}     &\bohr{}{Th}    &\bohr{}{U}&    \bohr{}{Np}     &\bohr{}{Pu}\\
    Actinium (89)   &Thorium (90)   &Uranium (92)   &Neptunium (93) &Plutonium (94)
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @RosesBouquet Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bohr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\setbohr{
shell-dist = 8mm,
insert-missing
}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CCC}
\bohr{}{C}
    &   \bohr{}{H}
        &   \bohr{}{O}         \\
\caption{Carbon}
    &   \caption{Hydrogen}  
        &   \caption{Oxygen}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]